# I cannot get slider inputs to modify a map in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, maps

I cannot get the map to react with the sliders. THe data was from https://www.kaggle.com/nasa/meteorite-landings/data#
when i move the sliders the map "refreshes" like it resets itself as if something were going to change but all of the data points show up on the graph. any help would be appreciated.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(leaflet)
library(ggplot2)

Meteor <- read.csv()
#to take all NA values out
ReMeteor <- na.omit(Meteor) #from now on using ReMeteor instead of Meteor

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

       titlePanel("Meteorite Landings"),

    # Sidebar with a sliders and checkbox
    sidebarLayout( position = "right",
        sidebarPanel(
                        #1st slider year range
                     sliderInput("years","The year the meteorite fell, or the year it was found ",
                                 min = min(ReMeteor$year),
                                 max = max(ReMeteor$year),
                                 step = 1,value = c(1399,2013),
                                 animate = TRUE),
                        #2nd slider mass range
                     sliderInput("masss","The mass of the meteorite, in grams", 
                                 min = min(ReMeteor$mass),
                                 max = max(ReMeteor$mass),
                                 step = 100,value = c(.010,60000000), 
                                 animate = TRUE),

                        #checkbox

                     selectInput("fall", 
                                        "Was meteorite seen falling or found?", 
                                        choices = sort(unique(ReMeteor$fall))),
                                         ),     


        mainPanel( leafletOutput("my_leaf",height = 650, width = 605),textOutput("text1"),textOutput("text2")


        ))))




 server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

     #i think this block of four was letting it refresh, although no changes

      filtered <- reactive({ 

          ReMeteor[ReMeteor$year >= input$years[1] & ReMeteor$year <= input$years[2],]
        ReMeteor[ReMeteor$mass >= input$masss[1] & ReMeteor$mass <= input$masss[2],]
     })
       #need last checkbox


       # filter(ReMeteor >= input$year[1] &
       #                  ReMeteor <= input$year[2]) %>%
       #       filter(ReMeteor >= input$mass[1] &
       #                  ReMeteor <= input$mass[2])%>%
       #   filter(ReMeteor = sort(unique(ReMeteor$fall)))


     # fitBounds()#here it is !!! https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/shiny.html search : fitbounds --- this too https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/markers.html




     output$my_leaf <- renderLeaflet({
         leaflet(data = filtered()) %>%
             addMiniMap(zoomLevelOffset = -4) %>%
             addProviderTiles("Esri.NatGeoWorldMap") 
         })
             #fitBounds(ReMeteor, ReMeteor$reclong,ReMeteor$reclat,ReMeteor$reclong,ReMeteor$reclat)


     observe({
         # year_ <-input$year
         # mass_ <-input$mass
         # fall_ <-input$fall
         # 
         leafletProxy("my_leaf", data = filtered()) %>% 
           clearShapes() %>%
           clearMarkers() %>% 
           clearPopups() %>%
                        addMarkers(lat = ReMeteor$reclat, 
                        lng = ReMeteor$reclong,
                        clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(),
                        popup = as.character(ReMeteor$name,ReMeteor$recclass))

     })

 output$text1 <- renderText({
     paste("You have chosen a range from the year", input$years[1], "to", input$years[2])
 })

 output$text2 <- renderText({
     paste("You have chosen a range of mass from", input$masss[1], "to", input$masss[2], "grams")
 })

})

 shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that although you correctly used the reactive value `filtered()` in your `leafletProxy` call, you use the non-reactive version of `ReMeteor` in your `addMarkers` call.

```
     observe({

         leafletProxy("my_leaf", data = filtered()) %>% 
           clearShapes() %>%
           clearMarkers() %>% 
           clearPopups() %>%
                        addMarkers(lat = filtered()$reclat, 
                        lng = filtered()$reclong,
                        clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(),
                        popup = as.character(filtered()$name,filtered()$recclass))
     })
```

[image]